# How to add multiple AND conditions to criteria in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am trying to add multiple 'and' conditions to criteria in Spring Data but not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.
Please refer the following code :

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("siteCode").is(siteCode));

        if(paymentMode != null) {
            criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("paymentMode").is(paymentMode));
        }
        if(planCode != null) {
            criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("packageCode").is(planCode));
        }
        if(status){
            criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("expiryDateTime").gt(new Date()));
        } else {
            criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("expiryDateTime").lte(new Date()));
        }

        Query query = new Query(criteria);

        List<UserPackage> userPackageList = mongoTemplate.find(query, UserPackage.class);
```

Comment: What do you mean? What are you AND'ing there?

Comment: For example : If planCode is not null, then it should be added to criteria like 
Criteria.where("siteCode").is(siteCode).and("planCode").is(planCode).

Comment: So, you just need to know what the AND (&&) operator is in java?

Comment: No man, I am trying to get the above code to work. I am sure that I am missing something, above code does not work.

Comment: As i mentioned in question,  AND'ing criteria not the if condition. Check those "criteria.andOperator" in code, I am trying to 'and' multiple query conditions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. You don't need to use method 'andOperator' and another Criteria inside.

It would simply work by using 'and' method and then chain the following operator method you want to use.

Sharing the working solution to help other newcomers like me.

```
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria = criteria.and("siteCode").is(siteCode);
        if (paymentMode != null) {
            criteria = criteria.and("paymentMode").is(paymentMode);
        }
        if (planCode != null) {
            criteria = criteria.and("packageCode").is(planCode);
        }
        if (status) {
            criteria = criteria.and("expiryDateTime").gt(new Date());
        } else {
            criteria = criteria.and("expiryDateTime").lte(new Date());
        }
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you want to add conditions for a date between and match another field, below is what I used.

```
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("date").gte(from).andOperator(Criteria.where("date").lt(to));

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(manager)) {
        criteria = criteria.and("manager").is(manager);
    }
```